# Django duplicate entry 1062

Tags: python, mysql, django

I ran `python manage.py migrate accounts zero` then i faced an error,
I checked my models multiple times it seems everything is ok but...!?

**This is the error:**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'accounts_post_user_id_ecf3e197_uniq'")
```

**User model**:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=191, unique=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin
```

**Post model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    hashed_id = models.CharField(max_length=191)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=270)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=191)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

There was 1 user with 2 posts.

Comment: You seem to set a unique restriction somewhere on the user id field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `unique=False` to **ForeignKey fields** and it solved the problem.

I hope if this error occurs in your app this answer gives you a hand.